# Entity Framework Plus clear cache for individual queries

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-plus

I am using FromCache() method whenever I need to retrieve data from the SQL database. There will be a lot of unique queries executed in a single method since it is getting data based on userID. The data associated with the userID will be updated through a separate process which will also trigger an event in the method that controls retrieving. When the data for a specific user is updated, I want to expire the cache for that user so that the next query on that userID will get the most recent data.

I see that EF plus has the option to ExpireTag. Would it be feasible to create a single tag for each userID and then use that to expire the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be feasible to create a single tag for each userID and then use that to expire the cache?

Yes, tag can be used similarly as if you use a cache key.

The best is probably using 2 tags:

- Users
- [UniqueUserId]

The `Users` tag will expire all cache related to "users"

The `[UniqueUserId]` tag will expire all caches related to this specific users